# Need help with structural induction proof.

Tags: logic, induction

I have to functions a(F) and |F| where F is a propositional formula
The first one return the number of all propositional variables and the second one returns the number of all propositional variables, brackets and connectors

ex:
a( (not b) ) = 1
|(not b)| = 4

I have to use structural induction to prove that for any formula F a(F) <= |F|

I don't really understand structural induction and I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: See [Structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) : "Structural induction is a proof method that is used in mathematical logic. It is a generalization of mathematical induction over natural numbers." " The structural induction proof is a proof that the proposition holds for all the *minimal structures*, and that if it holds for the immediate substructures of a certain structure $S$, then it must hold for $S$ also."

Comment: Here the "structure" involved is the inductive definition of formula : every prop var is a formula, and if $P,Q$ are prop vars, then $(\lnot P)$ and $( P\lor Q)$ are formulas.

Comment: Start : consider the formula $F$ formed by the single var $P$; then $a(F)=1$ and $|F|=1$. Thus $a(F) \le |F|$.

Comment: We have now to consider the cases : $\lnot$ and $\lor$. For the first one, let $F$ is $(\lnot R)$ and we know, by inductive hypotheses, that $a(R) \le |R|$. now $a(F)=a(R) \le |R| < |F|=|R|+3$. The same for $\lor$.

Comment: Start with writing out inductive definitions of both functions.